# xcode: guardar un valor de Label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app

No encuentro la solución que me funcione.

```
@IBOutlet weak var N1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var N2: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var P1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var P2: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var F1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var F2: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var res1: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func total(_ sender: Any) {


   let n1 = Double(N1.text!)
   let p1 = Double(P1.text!)
   let f1 = Double(n1! + p1!)

    F1.text = "\(f1)"


    let n2 = Double(N2.text!)
    let p2 = Double(P2.text!)
    let f2 = Double(n2! + p2!)

     F2.text = "\(f2)"        


    res1.text = "\(res1)"
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para coger los resultados que me salen en Label (`F1.text` / `F2.text`) y volver a sumarlos entre ellos dos apareciendo en otro Label (`res1`)? (Todo al clicar un mismo botón)

idea:

```
2+2=4
1+2=3

4+3=7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hola, intenta esto para ver si te funciona**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var F1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var F2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rest: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        F1.text = "1.23"
        F2.text = "2.00"
    }


    @IBAction func presionarBoton(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let f1 = Double(F1.text!), let f2 = Double(F2.text!) else {
            return
        }

        let suma = f1 + f2
        self.rest.text = String(suma)

    }

}
```

[image: Resultado]